# Reading SQL table from Python with merge condition

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={??};"
                      "Server=??;"
                      "Database=??;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")


df1 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM table1", conn)

df2 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table2  (((where id_key = id(from table1) ))) ", conn)
```

Hello,

I have two tables in SQL server. I wanted to pull the data from table2 that has the same ID which mean id_key = id(from table1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get df1's id as a tuple:

```
ids = tuple(df1['id'].to_list())
print(ids)
'''
(1, 2)
'''
```

then, use format and read sql:

```
sql= 'select*from table where id_key in {}'.format(ids)
print(sql)
'''
select*from table where id_key in (1, 2)
'''

df2=pd.read_sql(sql,conn)
```

full code:

```
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={??};"
                      "Server=??;"
                      "Database=??;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")


df1 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM table1", conn)

ids = tuple(df1['id'].to_list())
df2_sql = 'SELECT * FROM table2 where id_key in {}'.format(ids)

df2 = pd.read_sql_query(df2_sql, conn)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I appreciate it! However, I am still not be able to pull the data from SQL. Can I ask you to update the code assuming I have conn = pyodbc.connect()

pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Table2 where Prdm_Key in {}", conn).format(ids)

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes, It works if I already have the df2 like the example, but It does not work when I try to pull it from SQL

Comment: okey, can you share the error ?

Comment: TypeError: read_sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'con'

Comment: okey i edited the answer. i think, you have to add **conn** in **read_sql**

Comment: Sorry, still not working!

Comment: I think we are making a very simple mistake. Try reading df2 the same way you read df1. Just change the query (use the sql string we formatted)

Comment: But I just wanted the matched rows. I do not need the entire df2

Comment: I just updated the question. I do not know if it is clear now

Comment: i edited the answer. Can you check it ?